# Take average for duplicated entries score and convert in wide format

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, mean, reshape

I want to reshape the data in wide format, but I want to take the average of the third column associated with fourth column entries. Like `(0.21+0.05+0.06)/total`.
I have read about `reshape` package in R, but I do not know which aggregate function to use that finds the average before converting to wide format

Input data frame

```
CID100000085    C0000737      0.21        Abdominal pain
CID100000085    C0000737      0.21        Gastrointestinal pain
CID100000085    C0000737      0.05        Abdominal pain
CID100000085    C0000737      0.05        Gastrointestinal pain
CID100000085    C0000737      0.06        Abdominal pain
CID100000085    C0000737      0.06        Gastrointestinal pain
```

Desired Output

```
                                Abdominal pain   Gastrointestinal pain
   CID100000085    C0000737     0.0166           0.0166
```

Comment: Take a look at `?dcast` from `reshape2` or `?xtabs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), id1+id2~pain, value.var = "value", mean)
#            id1      id2 Abdominal pain Gastrointestinal pain
#1: CID100000085 C0000737      0.1066667             0.1066667
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id1 = c("CID100000085", "CID100000085", "CID100000085", 
"CID100000085", "CID100000085", "CID100000085"), id2 = c("C0000737",  
 "C0000737", "C0000737", "C0000737", "C0000737", "C0000737"), 
value = c(0.21, 0.21, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06), pain = c("Abdominal pain", 
"Gastrointestinal pain", "Abdominal pain", "Gastrointestinal pain", 
"Abdominal pain", "Gastrointestinal pain")), 
.Names = c("id1", 
"id2", "value", "pain"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `aggregate` together with `reshape` in base R:

```
reshape(aggregate(V3~V1+V2+V4, df, mean), 
        idvar = "V1", timevar = "V4", direction = "wide")[,-4]

#            V1 V2.Abdominalpain V3.Abdominalpain V3.Gastrointestinalpain
#1 CID100000085         C0000737        0.1066667               0.1066667
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CID100000085", class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "C0000737", class = "factor"), 
    V3 = c(0.21, 0.21, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06), V4 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Abdominalpain", "Gastrointestinalpain"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```